# How to order with mysql query only products which has biggest price ratio between price and promo_price

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT id,bg_product_name,product_price,promo_price FROM products 
WHERE active="1" order by ((product_price / promo_price) > 0) ASC limit 5
```

Sample records:

```
#id #bg_product_name  #product_price  #promo_price
74  Jewellery         30.00            28.00
75  Jewellery1        20.00            0.00
76  Jewellery2        30.00            25.00
```

and so on.
My query returns records but they are not sorted by biggest price difference.

Full query:

```
SELECT 
p.id, bg_product_name, unique_name, product_price, promo_price,
 promo_end_date, available_qty, model, p.added_date, url, bg_category, free_delivery, 
free_option,supplier_name,link_name, (product_price / promo_price) as  p_ratio 
FROM 
products p, products_to_categories ptc, products_to_adverts pta, products_categories pc, adverts a 
WHERE 
p.id=ptc.product_id and ptc.category_id="156" and ptc.category_id=pc.id
 and p.active="1" having p_ratio > 0 and p.instock="1" and p.id=pta.product_id and
 available_qty > 0 AND pta.advert_id=a.id AND 
pta.advert_id not in (0) 
GROUP BY ptc.product_id order by p_ratio DESC,p.updated_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: ((product_price / promo_price) > 0)  ? did you try like this ((product_price / promo_price) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a HAVING clause as in the accepted answer you can use a WHERE clause, which in most cases is better performance-wise  ...under one condition: There are no negative (promo_)prices (a reasonable assumption, I think?)
In that case there is only one value you have to take care of: promo_price==0 as in your Jewellery1 example. The "ratio" for that record would be 20.0/0.0 -> NULL. Any other value for promo_price will result in a positive number for the ratio.
So, just filter out records with promo_price=0.0 before something else is done.

```
SELECT
    id,bg_product_name,product_price,promo_price, (product_price/promo_price) as ratio
FROM
    products 
WHERE
    active="1"
    AND promo_price > 0
ORDER BY
    ratio ASC
LIMIT
    5
```

Or maybe even better: Also keep the records having promo_price=0 in the list, but assign a distinct value to ratio, e.g.

```
SELECT
    id,bg_product_name,product_price,promo_price,
    if(promo_price>0, product_price/promo_price, 'free as in beer') as ratio
FROM
    products 
WHERE
    active="1"
ORDER BY
    ratio ASC
LIMIT
    5
```

Comment: on second thougt the second suggestion may not be a good idea. IIRC the optimizer doesn't like it too much when you assign different datatypes (a number vs a string) to one field ....but anyway. Use a pre-defined number for that value (e.g -1 or 9999.9) if that becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You might try this :

```
SELECT id,bg_product_name,product_price,promo_price 
FROM products 
WHERE active="1" 
ORDER BY ABS(product_price - promo_price) ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
SELECT id, bg_product_name, product_price, promo_price, (product_price / promo_price) as p_ratio  FROM products 
WHERE active="1" GROUP BY products.id having p_ratio > 0 order by p_ratio ASC limit 5
```

order must be DESC

Comment: Devendra you were first and thats why I accept your answer in 2 mins Thanks !, Thank you all guys !

Comment: having p_ratio > 0 eliminates all rows with promo_price=0.00 thats why this answer is most correct !

Comment: In that case could you please change your question text from "biggest price difference between price and promo_price" to "biggest **ratio** of price to promo_price"; because otherwise any answer with "price divided by promo_price" is just flat wrong.

Comment: Your are right, this way sounds confusing maybe, I will correct it

Comment: Devendra on some reason when change my code in the full query I got error :
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY ptc.product_id order by p_ratio DESC,p.updated_date DESC LIMIT 5' at line 4

Comment: Working ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

try this:add `(product_price / promo_price)` to select clause then do order by. add `ratio > 0` in where clause if you don't need `0`.

```
SELECT id,bg_product_name,product_price,promo_price,(product_price / promo_price) as ratio FROM products 
WHERE active="1" and ratio > 0 order by ratio ASC limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT id,bg_product_name,product_price,promo_price,(product_price / promo_price) AS newDiff FROM products 
WHERE active="1" order by newDiff) ASC limit 5
```